# searching two identical submatrices in a bigger matrix

Tags: string, matrix, pattern-matching, submatrix

I need to find two identical submatices in a larger matrix.
I am not getting how to approach as first I need to have a submatrice and then to find if its identical is present or not.

e.g.
(N X M) 4X5 matrix

xy***yyx***

yx***xyy***

x***yyx***y

x***xyy***x

Identicals are

yyx

xyy

present at bold letters made points.. N,M <=10

not sure where to start with..

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

What are the limits on the submatrix?  E.g., can you have a 1x1 submatrix?  If there are no limits, then a dynamic programming approach would seem to be in order.

I.e., find the 1x1 matching submatrices, then use that as a starting point to find 2x2, 3x3, etc.